# Raising the nofile limit under WSL2

Tags: config, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm not what you would call an advanced linux user, so my apologies for a probably dumb question.

I'm trying to raise the NOFILE limit for my UBUNTU 20.04 distro using WSL2, following this guide: [cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/1200539/cannot-increase-open-file-limit-past-4096-ubuntu/1200818#1200818?s=1b927bb17396480da98a94cbacf8da62)

However, when I try to modify the corresponding `.conf` files I get a permision denied error.
When trying to do so from windows and VsCode I get:

```
Failed to save 'system.conf': Command failed: "C:\Users\sague\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --file-write "c:\Users\sague\AppData\Roaming\Code\code-elevated-mjlcag" "\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\etc\systemd\system.conf" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\etc\systemd\system.conf'
```

And when trying to do so using nano within the WSL2 terminal (using windows terminal) I get:

```
 Error writing /etc/systemd/system.conf: Permission denied
```

Please help, I'm stuck with this :')
My apologies for what is probably a very noob question

Comment: Did you try opening it in the editor as administrator?

Comment: I see a downvote, probably because the title makes it sound like this is a general-use question (and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is for *programming*).  I'm giving this one a pass, though, since raising the ULIMIT is almost always for development reasons.  That said, @sguerraty, given the way this is worded, it *probably* would have been a better fit on Super User.  I've at least edited the title to make it more relevant to what you are really asking (and more development related).

Comment: My bad I forgot to add that the error when using VS code is when trying to save the file as admin, otherwise it will raise an error requesting the "save" be done as admin.
Trying to save as admin is when I get that error. My best guess is that it is using a windows admin user but not one for wsl, though I don't know my way arround linux or WSL2 enough to say for sure. @BrianThompson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, to be honest you *are* making a few newbie mistakes, but don't worry - Even once you get past those, what you are trying to do under WSL *isn't* easy.

1. First, you are trying to edit a system file as a normal user in `nano`, resulting in `Permission denied`.  Solution:  Use `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system.conf` instead.  But see below (3) for why this ultimately isn't going to work.
2. Second, you are trying to edit a WSL system file as a normal user under VSCode.  This just won't work since VSCode always runs as the normal user by design.  It may be possible to get it to run under `sudo`, but it's probably not worth the effort.  Note that this is also a limitation when running the "Remote - SSH" extension in VSCode (similar to the "Remote - WSL" one you are using now).
3. You are trying to modify the `systemd` configuration under WSL, where there is no `systemd` support, so even when you do successfully edit the file, it isn't going to do anything.
4. Your next attempt once you got past that would probably be (as it is for most of us) to try to raise the ulimit through `/etc/security/limits.conf`, which *is* the right way to do it, but requires a trick under WSL.  That file is a PAM construct, and ... well, PAM runs at login, and we don't "login" in WSL, so PAM usually doesn't get called.

The hacky solution, as I cover [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1327539/1165986) on Ask Ubuntu (with great assistance from a number of answers in [this Github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1688#issuecomment-532767317)) is to make the modifications to `/etc/security/limits.conf` and then to force PAM to process it by `sudo`'ing back in as your own user via:

```
sudo su $USER
```

or possibly

```
sudo su - $USER # if you need to run as a login shell
```

There are also some other suggestions in the Github thread, if those incantations don't quite work for you.

Comment: This appears to work :D (at least within the shell, I'll try my python script tomorrow)
Thanks so much, and again my apologies for a noob question in the wrong place, to be honest I was not familiar with super user, since I spend most of my time here and Math stack exchange (no excuse I know).
Anyway, Thank u again :)

Comment: To add a bit more info, I was also not correctly specifying the user "name" within the limits.conf file and used 'su <username> --shell /bin/bash' and that did the trick

Comment: Cool - Good to hear it's working, and like I said, while Super User might be a slightly better fit, it's something you have to do for *development* purposes, so it's *acceptable* (IMHO) for Stack Overflow.